# Images failing to load for me or everyone?

Tags: discussion, bug

Seems I can't add more than 1 image to an answer and that image is *always* converted to the same incorrect image...

See here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/144370/3270

Just me or an imgr issue at the moment?

testing....

[image]

Same thing happens on meta....

Comment: This is a network-wide issue, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359772/295232

Comment: ....... Thanks @Glorfindel

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel. I've added your comment as an answer because people often overlook comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange is experiencing a network-wide issue with the wrong pictures showing up for all uploaded images: [I am getting the wrong image when uploading a picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359772/i-am-getting-the-wrong-image-when-uploading-a-picture)

A workaround is to upload the image on [Imgur](https://imgur.com) itself instead of through the uploader and then inserting the resulting ID in your post.

EDIT: seems like it was fixed by Imgur.

Comment: Manually uploading to imgr and copying the link does work https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/144370/3270 -- I think that's the first time I've ever actually visited the imgr site.. how ugly `:)` -- Thanks Pie~